# problema al hacer una consulta con like en sql server y la cadena a buscar tiene un cero (0) al comienzo

Tags: sql-server

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Buenas amigo si me pueden asesorar con este problema , cuando hago la consulta y el la cadena tiene un cero (0) al comienzo no hace la busqueda bien. si le quito el cero (0) si la hace bien la busqueda. 
Gracias por el apoyo.!

Comment: Por favor no publiques imágenes con código, publica el texto de tus consultas directamente en la pregunta. Un saludo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al llamar al procedimiento no le pases el ID como un número sino como un string

Cambia tu llamada de la siguiente imagen por esto (fíjate en que ahora tiene comillas):

```
exec Abonados_tarjeta_getall_ID '01212121212'
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Listo perfecto. Solucionado. Gracias